# WooCommerce cart fragments isn't updated after ajax adding items

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

This is the code that I have on my products page template.

```
<p>Your total: <span class="r_cart_total"><?= WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></span></p>
```

So whenever a product is added to cart, I have a filter that works

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'wc_refresh_cart_fragments', 50, 1 );
function wc_refresh_cart_fragments( $fragments ){

    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
    // Normal version
    $count_normal = '<span class="r_cart_total">' .  $cart_total . '</span>';
    $fragments['.r_cart_total'] = $count_normal;

    return $fragments;
}
```

According to this function I am updating the span content with class '.r_cart_total'.
This function works fine when an item is removed from the cart, but whenever I add a product to cart the fragments do not get updated.

Here is the add to cart function

```
/**
* Add to cart product using ajax
**/
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {

    $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
    $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
    $variation_id = absint($_POST['variation_id']);
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
    $product_status = get_post_status($product_id);
    $is_buy_all = filter_var($_POST['is_buy_all'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    
    //if buy all product then remove all other products in the cart
    if($is_buy_all){
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
             WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
        }
    }
    
    if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) {
        
        do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);
        
        //show success message add to cart
        if ('yes' === get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true);
        }
        
        if($is_buy_all && !empty($_POST['sub_products'])){
            $sub_products = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['sub_products']));
            foreach($sub_products as $sub_product){
                $sub_product = trim($sub_product);
                $sub_product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($sub_product));
                $quantity = 1;
                $variation_id = absint($variation_id);
                $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $sub_product_id, $quantity);
                $sub_product_status = get_post_status($sub_product_id);
                if($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($sub_product_id, $quantity) && 'publish' === $sub_product_status) {
                    do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $sub_product_id);
                }
            }
        }
        
        WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments();
        wp_die();
    } else {

        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));

        echo wp_send_json($data);
        wp_die();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have added the code for add to cart.

Comment: Where is the js code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245975/discussion-between-milind-prajapati-and-bhautik).